# Call Google API with Powershell

Tags: powershell, curl

I want to call Google APIs from Powershell. The google documentation says:

```
curl "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" 
  -d "client_id=$CLIENT_ID&client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET&code=$CODE&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
```

Which works when executed from the commandline.

I tried to convert this to powershell like:

```
$token = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body "client_id=x&client_secret=y&code=z&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
```

And like:

```
$tokenParams = @{
  client_id='x';
  client_secret='y';
  code='z';
  grant_type='authorization_code';
  redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
}

$token = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $tokenParams
```

Both return:

`Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.`

How to properly convert curl to Invoke-WebRequest or another PS cmdlet?

Comment: Also look into `Invoke-RestMethod` which I is available in Powershell V3 and later.

Comment: However, the real issue here is that you're passing the object as a body. All of Google's APIs want these as Parameters, which are in the request headers, not the body. Also, have you looked at this free implementation of the API for powershell https://github.com/squid808/gShell/

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you use *Invoke-WebRequest* right as the POST request's body should have *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* content type which is set by default in PS.

I executed the same code and I got a 401 request, because my auth parameters doesn't match. I also checked it in Fiddler too and the message is constructed correctly

Mine Fiddler captured Invoke-WebRequest POST message looks like:

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 6.4; hu-HU) WindowsPowerShell/5.0.9879.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Length: 113
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=urn%3aietf%3awg%3aoauth%3a2.0%3aoob&code=z&client_id=x&client_secret=y
```

According to Google's oauth sample message ( https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices ) this is correct, so I would check your call in Fiddler too.