# Deleting Gmail Emails via Google API using Powershell v2.0

Tags: powershell, google-api, gmail, google-oauth, powershell-2.0

```
$user = "example@gmail.com"
$pass= "examplepassword" 
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $user -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($pass, $secpasswd)

Invoke-RestMethod  'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/0' -Method Delete -Credentials $cred
```

So, my problem here is twofold.

I originally tried using [Invoke-WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) to delete gmail emails via the Google API with a http delete request. However, this did not work because `Powershell 2.0 does not support Invoke-WebRequest`.

Thereafter, I turned to attempting to utilize [Invoke-RestMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) after experimentation with IMAP and POP3, which both required external dependencies (Adding .dlls to the machines I am working with is not optimal).

Therefore, if someone could show me the appropriate way to delete an email via the Google API in Powershell, I would appreciate it. I have provided some sample code as to what I am working with above. Please excuse any mistakes it may contain, as I am relatively new to Powershell, and my experience remains limited in working with RESTful services.

Comment: Have you looked at [technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/64c74e89-610e-4229-a56b-12f973232a0a/replace-invokerestmethod-in-powershell-20?forum=ITCG)?

Comment: I have looked at Technet, yes. It does not exactly provide examples as to how it interacts with Google's OAuth2.0 and their API, so that is where I ran into the issue.

Comment: Invoke-restmethod is also a PoSH 3 and above cmdlet.

Comment: Fun.... Well, at least I am getting another node on which to run this on which should have Powershell v5 enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GMail API is going to require Oauth2 authentication unless this is a gsuit / domain admin / GMail account in which case you can use a service account for authentication.  In either case you cant use login and password.

My powershell knowledge is very limited have you considered doing this directly though the mail server [IMAP and SMTP](http://IMAP%20and%20SMTP) and not using the API.  No idea if that's possible or not with powershell

Update:

I was able to do it using Invoke-WebRequest you will still need to get an access token first.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/0?access_token=$accesstoken"-Method Get | ConvertFrom-Json
```

seams to also work

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/0?access_token=$accesstoken"-Method Get
```

Put up a the code for OAuth on GitHub if your interested:  [Google Oauth Powershell](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/55115de5e8b366be3969b24884f30a39)

Comment: Seams Oauth2 is also possible with powershell you have me intrigued I am playing with it. following this one now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658610/call-google-api-with-powershell

Comment: In theory, it is possible, but it requires dependencies similar to AE.Net.Mail.dll utilized here https://github.com/nikoblag/Gmail.ps. For portability's sake, utilizing a .dll is not a possibility. I have no idea how I would go about using IMAP directly from Powershell without it, though.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, I will check to see if that works with my solution tomorrow morning.

Comment: Any idea how this might work with Powershell v2? I would like to get all this to work on my legacy machine anyways. Maybe POP3 might work in C# integrated into a Powershell script? Here is a link to that: https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail/blob/master/Pop3Client.cs

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea how C# works, and I probably won't be able to get that to work on my own.

Comment: Why use the mail server and not Oauth your question is about the api not the mail server might want to start a different question if you are going to go a different way now that I have shown you how to do it with the api

Comment: Yeah, probably a good idea. I will submit another question and accept your answer, because it does answer the original question.

Comment: Anyways, after much thought and figuring out an alternative implementation to solve my problem, I am going to review your answer and probably end up using it in some format.

Comment: Well, I ended up using it, but now, of course I got stuck on figuring out the MIME / Base64 Invoke-WebRequest to send emails. However, your information worked perfectly and I really appreciate that you took the time to write that despite the fact that I didn't have time to implement it when you originally made it.

Comment: If it helps I havent been able to get it to send an email that is readable yet either.   I am still working on it.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. The API isn't simple in its specifications for this function, that is for sure.

Comment: Any progress on that yet?